# Unique Partitioning of Integers in Java with Speedup - Unidentifiable Flaw in Algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, integer, structure

I asked a question over at CodeReview ([Optimizing unique partitions of integers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45910/optimizing-unique-partitions-of-integers/45921?noredirect=1#comment80623_45921)) and got some good feedback regarding how to optimize the code. I have spent the last week or so attempting to get the optimization correct (namely, implementing the Map structure to reference the already-partitioned integers so they don't need to be calculated again and again), but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this properly.

The purpose of this code is to generate all unique partitions, ideally stored in some sort of data structure, of a certain integer. I.e., if I gave the program a number, say, 5, it would give output of

```
[[5],[4,1],[3,2]]
```

and not

```
[[5],[4,1],[3,2],[3,1,1], [2,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]
```

Here is a benchmark class by which I run my tests (the working code that, while slow, will generate correct results):

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;


public class UniquePartition {

    private int n;
    private ArrayList<Set<Integer>> allPartitions;

    //Constructs the object with integer. Sets the target and then calculates partitions.
    public UniquePartition(int num) {
        n = num;
        allPartitions = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
        allPartitions = findPartitions();

    }

    //Returns partitions without calculating them.
    public List<Set<Integer>> getPartitions() {
        return allPartitions;
    }

    //Returns the nth partition without calculating them.
    public Set<Integer> getPartitionN(int n) {
    //  ArrayList<ArrayList<BigInteger>> partitions = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BigInteger>>();
        return allPartitions.get(n);
    }

    // Returns an ArrayList containing ArrayLists, each of which is a single partition. Should never be called, otherwise
    // will redo calculation.
    public ArrayList<Set<Integer>> findPartitions() {
        ArrayList<Set<Integer>> pS = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
        Set<Integer> empty = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        pS = findPartitions(pS,n,n,empty);
        return pS;
    }

    //Stores the partitions in an ArrayList<String>. Never used alone. getAllPartitions() is the driver for this method.
    public ArrayList<Set<Integer>> findPartitions(ArrayList<Set<Integer>> p, int target, int maxValue, Set<Integer> suffix) {

            //If the target is zero, it adds the built up suffix to p.
            if (target==0) {
                p.add(suffix);
            }

            //Otherwise, it adds more things to the suffix.
            else {

                    //If maxValue is greater than 1, it sees what happens if maxValue is dropped one.
                    //If it's still too high, rinse and repeat. When it fails (and it will), it uses the previous
                    //maxValue number and continues onward.
                    if (maxValue>1) {

                        findPartitions(p, target, maxValue-1, suffix);
                    }

                    //If trying again failed (and it eventually will), it creates a newSuff Set and add the old suffix to it.
                    Set<Integer> newSuff = new TreeSet<Integer>();
                    newSuff.addAll(suffix);



                    //Then, it checks if the maxValue is less than (or equal to) the target AND if the suffix contains the maxValue.
                    //If so, it adds the maxValue to the newSuffix and then repeats the whole process with the old suffix replaced with the
                    //newSuffix.
                    if (maxValue<=target && !suffix.contains(maxValue)) {
                        newSuff.add(maxValue);

                        ArrayList<Set<Integer>> tempPart = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
                        Set<Integer> tempSuff = new TreeSet<Integer>();

                        findPartitions(p, target-maxValue, maxValue, newSuff);

                    }
                }

        //Finally, it returns all of the added suffixes in the form of p.
        return p;
    }
}
```

This code is run with this driver:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long nanos =0;
        int target = 10;

        nanos = System.nanoTime();
        UniquePartition part = new UniquePartition(target);
        System.out.println(part.getPartitions());
        nanos = System.nanoTime() - nanos;


        System.out.println("1: "+nanos/1000000.0+"ms");
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly, if a bit slow (when trying to find unique partitions of integers 100 or above). After posting my question over at CodeReview, I got some advice as to how to speed it up; specifically, I was enlightened to the idea that I could just calculate each partition of the integers required in the partitions of the target value once and then save them in a Map structure. I've tried implementing that below:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;


public class UniquePartitionTest2 {

    private int n;
    private List<Set<Integer>> allPartitions;
    private Map<Integer, List<Set<Integer>>> map;
    private String testString;
    private List<Set<Integer>> tempP;
    private Set<Integer> tempTree;
    private int calls;

    //Constructs the object with integer. Sets the target and then calculates partitions.
    public UniquePartitionTest2(int num) {
        n = num;
        map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Set<Integer>>>();
        allPartitions = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
        testString = " ";
        calls = 0;

    }   

    //Returns partitions without calculating them.
    public List<Set<Integer>> getPartitions() {
        allPartitions = findPartitions();
        return allPartitions;
    }

    //Returns the nth partition without calculating them.
    public Set<Integer> getPartitionN(int n) {
        if(allPartitions == null)
            allPartitions = findPartitions();
        return allPartitions.get(n);
    }

    /**  
     * Returns an ArrayList containing ArrayLists, each of which is a single partition. Should never be called, otherwise
     * will redo calculation.
     */
    public ArrayList<Set<Integer>> findPartitions() {
        ArrayList<Set<Integer>> pS = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
        Set<Integer> empty = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        pS = findPartitions(pS,n,n,empty,false);
        return pS;
    }

    /**  
     *  Stores the partitions in an ArrayList<String>. Never used alone. getAllPartitions() is the driver for this method.
     */
    public ArrayList<Set<Integer>> findPartitions(ArrayList<Set<Integer>> p, int target, int maxValue, Set<Integer> suffix, boolean needToAdd) {

        if(!map.containsKey(target) && needToAdd) {
            ArrayList<Set<Integer>> tempP = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
            Set<Integer> tempSuff = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            tempP = findPartitions(tempP,target,target,tempSuff,false);
            map.put(target,tempP);
        }

        //If the target is zero, it adds the built up suffix to p.
        if (target==0) {
            p.add(suffix);
        }

        //Otherwise, it adds more things to the suffix.
        else {
            if(map.containsKey(target-maxValue)) {
                System.out.println("Look up partition of "+(target-maxValue)+" which is "+map.get(target-maxValue).toString());
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Return the partition of "+target);

                if (maxValue>1) {
                    findPartitions(p, target, maxValue-1, suffix,false);
                }

                Set<Integer> newSuff = new TreeSet<Integer>();
                newSuff.addAll(suffix);
                newSuff.add(maxValue);

                //Then, it checks if the maxValue is less than (or equal to) the target AND if the suffix contains the maxValue.
                //If so, it adds the maxValue to the newSuffix and then repeats the whole process with the old suffix replaced with the
                //newSuffix.
                if (maxValue<=target && !suffix.contains(maxValue)) {

                    //If map doesn't contain the target, it sets boolean needToAdd to true so that the method knows
                    //to do a calculation on that target value (so that it adds it to the map)
                    if(!map.containsKey(target))
                        needToAdd = true;

                    //If the map contains target-maxValue, then it checks if there is overlap between the mapping and the newSuffix,
                    //and if the intersection is zero, then it adds the newSuffix to the List of partitions. It does this for every
                    //partition that target-maxValue maps to.
                    if(map.containsKey(target-maxValue)) {
                        for(int i=0;i<map.get(target-maxValue).size();i++) {
                            newSuff = new TreeSet<Integer>();
//                          System.out.println("suffix is "+suffix.toString()+", maxValue is "+maxValue+", and mapping is "+map.get(target-maxValue).get(i));
                            newSuff.addAll(suffix);
                            newSuff.add(maxValue);
                            Set<Integer> mappedSuff = map.get(target-maxValue).get(i);

                            if(getIntersection(newSuff,mappedSuff)==0) {
                                newSuff.addAll(map.get(target-maxValue).get(i));
//                              System.out.println("newSuff is "+newSuff.toString());
                                p.add(newSuff);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Otherwise, it actually calculates the partitions of target-maxValue.
                    //I think this is where the problem comes from, but I am not sure. The recursion of this algorithm
                    //is really throwing me for a loop - it's been so long in construction I've lost track of the structure.
                    else {
                        newSuff.addAll(suffix);
                        newSuff.add(maxValue);
                        findPartitions(p, target-maxValue, maxValue, newSuff,needToAdd);
                    }
                }
            }

        //Finally, it returns all of the added suffixes in the form of p.    
        return p;
    }

    public static int getIntersection(Set<Integer> set1, Set<Integer> set2) {
        boolean set1IsLarger = set1.size() > set2.size();
        Set<Integer> cloneSet = new HashSet<Integer>(set1IsLarger ? set2 : set1);
        cloneSet.retainAll(set1IsLarger ? set1 : set2);
        return cloneSet.size();
    }
}
```

The driver class is identical to the one above except with UniquePartition replaced by UniquePartitionTest2.

Some output from the two programs, with target = 7:

```
UniquePartitionTest2: [[1, 2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [2, 5], [1, 6], [7]]
UniquePartition: [[1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [2, 5], [1, 6], [7]]
1: 2.805509ms; 2: 0.33392ms
```

So a few problems in this output to note: first, the output from UniquePartitionTest2 has repeated elements. I have tried fixing this by using a set structure instead of a List structure, but that doesn't solve the problem as to why it's TRYING to add another element to the list it already has. I know there is an easy fix for this (check if its there, if not, don't add it) but I can't figure out why, algorithmically, it's trying to add this extra element.

Secondly, it's significantly slower than the UniquePartition class. This class is supposed to be faster, because it calculates all of the partitions of each integer it will use in advance, but it doesn't, and I am not sure why.

Anyone have any ideas as to what's causing this bizarre behavior? What's wrong with my algorithm/implementation?